# Django - logging unique ID

Tags: python, django, logging

I am assigning a unique ID to every incoming request and want to this to be automatically included in the logs whenever logging is done (without explicitly including it in all places).  I am using a middleware to generate and store this unique ID in a thread local.

I want to modify Django's logging formatter to include this unique ID directly:

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
    'formatters': {
        'full': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(name)s - %(message)s',
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

How do I add the unique id component to the formatter without explicitly adding at each log statement?

Comment: I guess you will have to write a custom formatter that uses a class variable to generate ids and the use it in the LOGGING dictionary

Comment: For people looking to use this with Apache's `mod_unique_id` and `django-log-unique-id` - you need to add a Django settings: `LOG_REQUEST_ID_HEADER = "UNIQUE_ID"` plus an Apache config: `RequestHeader set UNIQUE_ID "%{UNIQUE_ID}e"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Filter`: the technique is described in [this post](http://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html). Though it refers to IP addresses, you can just as easily use the approach to log your unique request IDs.